# How to delete all of the posts made by one user to a Facebook group?

Tags: facebook, spam-prevention, facebook-groups

I am running a Facebook group and we do not accept spam posts. Sometimes, a spammer will post 100+ status updates in just 1 minute. It is very difficult to remove all (100+) posts one by one.

Is there any way that I can delete all of this user's posts very fast from within Facebook?

Comment: You can simply add **Post Approval** All group posts must be approved by an admin or a moderator.

Comment: @Jonsca
I want to delete post,
Not comment.

Comment: @Aidono-63 As far as I can tell, "messages" covers status updates, etc.  If that is not the case, I will be happy to reopen this for you.

Comment: @jonsca pls opean this post.
And i am not developer to my own graph api script.

Comment: @Aidono-63 Does "messages" not cover status updates?  I honestly do not know, but I can't imagine that it means private messages.